# jQuery replace old ID with new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace my old ID with new one but this function is not working. How can I resolve this error?

```js
$("#addfield").click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('id')+1);
    $(this).data('id', + $('#addfield').data('id')+1);
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-success addfield" id="addfield" class="addfield" data-id="1">Add field</a>
```

Comment: For what reason do you need to do this? `id` attributes are intended to be immutable. You should try not to change them after the page has loaded, if at all possible

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the issue is he uses post-inc instead of pre-inc. I added an answer

Comment: I know, but my point is that dynamically changing `id` isn't a good idea in the first place.

Comment: I agree with that. better he could toggle with classes if the purpose is to apply styles @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan totally true it's not recommended to change the id after page load many events rely on the id.

Comment: I update my code it not updating value of data id please help me

Comment: It is. check the question snippet now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you increase value after setting `newValue`.

In this line: `var newvalue = currentvalue++`; it is happening two things:

**1)** var newvalue=currentvalue;

**2)** currentvalue=currentvalue+1

```js
$(".addfield").click(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-id', +$(this).attr('data-id')+1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-success addfield" data-id="1" class="addfield">Add field</a>
```

Comment: I update my code it not updating value of data id please help me

Comment: @RushabhShah, thanks ! It is working my answer for you ?

Comment: Yes but now I am finding for data-id not for simple ID attribute

Comment: It contains solution with `data-id`

Comment: People with too many points are downvoting the newcomers question and  answers because they are afraid of beginners.

Answer (score 3):

#### The problem

`var newvalue = currentvalue++;`

When this executed, the value of `newvalue` is 1 and then only `currentvalue` change to 2.

Because it is post increment.

Change it to pre-increment

```js
$(".addfield").click(function(){
      var currentvalue = $(this).attr('id');
      var newvalue = ++currentvalue;
      $('.addfield').attr('id', newvalue);
      alert(currentvalue);
      console.log($(".addfield"));
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-success addfield" id="1" class="addfield">Add field</a>
```

Comment: I update my code it not updating value of data id please help me

Comment: @RushabhShah, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Ok. fine. But the code in the updated question is already working fine.

Comment: @SagarV yes your code is working but your code is not working with data attribute

Comment: @SagarV Yes Rory McCrossan said dynamic  updating ID is bad practice so I updated question to data-id

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP updated and added a new question, I am adding the new answer.

Note : The Attribute value is String. So, you need to convert it to int using `parseInt` as below. Check the code.

To change data-id,

```js
$("#addfield").click(function(){
    alert(parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'))+1);
    $(this).attr('data-id', + parseInt($('#addfield').attr('data-id'))+1);
    console.log($(this));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-success addfield" id="addfield" class="addfield" data-id="1">Add field</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, this working with numeric Id.

```js
$(".addfield").click(function(){
      var currentvalue = $(this).attr('id');alert("Old Id="+currentvalue);
      var newvalue = currentvalue++;
      $('.addfield').attr('id', newvalue);
      alert("New Id="+currentvalue++);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addfield" id="1">Click Here</div>
```

Comment: I update my code it not updating value of data id please help me